# Cannot remove an object from ArrayList<Object> saved in json

Tags: android, arraylist, gson

I have a shopping cart where I want to remove a product there, but I'm facing an issue. I can add product to the shopping cart and I save to shared preferences, but when I want to remove it but doesn't work. Here what I did:

```
holder.removeProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(ITEMS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = preferences.getString("artikujtShporta", "");
            ArrayList<Artikujt> artikullObject = gson
                    .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType());

            if (artikullObject != null) {
                artikullObject.remove(artikulli);
                String jsonString = gson.toJson(artikullObject);
                mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", jsonString);
                mEditor.apply();
            } else {
                ArrayList<Artikujt> arrayArtikuj = new ArrayList<>();
                arrayArtikuj.remove(artikulli);
                Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Artikujt>>(){}.getType();
                String s = gson.toJson(arrayArtikuj, listOfTestObject);
                mEditor.putString("artikujtShporta", s);
                mEditor.apply();
            }
        });
```

The same thing I did for adding the product, with the difference that here I call

```
artikullObject.remove(artikulli);
```

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

**What is the problem?**

The problem here will be that the instance of your class `Artikujt` which you want to delete from the Array is not the same as you have read out of the Preferences.

As soon as you use `Gson` to make your String to a new Array it will generate completely new instances of your class and obviously these will not be the same as you had before. Maybe they are equal, but they are not the same instances.

**What can you do to solve this?**

I am assuming that you want to have each `Artikujt` only once. What means you could also use a `HashSet`. The advantage of this is it would would use the `hashCode()` function to determine which instance in the set you want to remove. So you just need to override this `hashCode()` function in your model class and use all of its properties to calculate the hashcode. You can find a example here: `https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-implement-javas-hashcode-correctly/`

**Sidenote**

Your else block is unnecessary. It doesn't make a lot of sense. You are creating a empty ArrayList, then you remove sth from this empty list and then you save this empty List into the shared preferences. The logic of your code wouldn't change if you would just remove this else block.